# Accessing Recycle Bin from Sitecore in C#

Tags: c#, sitecore, archive

My goal is to access the Recycle Bin from Sitecore in C# code and return the items from the bin as a list for data-read manipulation.

My current code is based on what I can find of documentation on Google, and my own experience, but it doesn't seem to actually contain what it claims to:

```
var recycleBinItems = Sitecore.Context.Database.Archives["recyclebin"].GetEntries(0, int.MaxValue);
var binItems = recycleBinItems as IList<ArchiveEntry> ?? recycleBinItems.ToList();

foreach (var item in binItems)
{
    Response.Write(item.Name);
}
```

The above should simply get a list of ArchiveEntries from the Archive "recyclebin" which is the one from Sitecore (URL.COM/Sitecore).

However, the result is as following:

[image]

This is ofcourse not the expected result, since I was asking for entries of recycle bin and not their properties/settings (Or whatever it's returning)

I've asked around my workplace, and no one seems to know where to access it, I hope someone can help me out here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore provides the `ArchiveManager` for accessing the recycle bin.

```
string archiveName = "recyclebin";
var database = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master"); // Get content database

Archive archive = Sitecore.Data.Archiving.ArchiveManager.GetArchive(archiveName, database);
```

Then use the `archive.GetEntriesForUser` method to retrieve the archived items.

Comment: That was it! Works perfectly now without any problem. Appreciate it man!